# Как использовать результат выполнения процедуры?

Tags: mysql, sql

Мне надо сделать что-то вроде `select * from call myproc(123)`. Т.е. использовать селектнутую процедурой таблицу. Не смог нагуглить это...

Comment: Нет такого. Ибо формально результат работы процедуры может содержать несколько наборов данных.

Comment: @Akina можно было бы использовать последний результа или разрешить возврат селекта из функций... Печаль. Что же мне делать. :(

Comment: *Что же мне делать* Искать другой  путь, а не вертеться на одном месте.

Comment: Ok :( К черту принцип DRY! Будем писать одно и то же по 10 раз!

Comment: Если Вы не видите иного пути - это не означает, что его нет...

Comment: @Akina ну есть еще идея зайти со стороны языка (я на пхп пишу). Просто мне казалось будет удобнее на SQL все это сделать.

Comment: *есть еще идея зайти со стороны языка* Идея по определению плохая. Даже не рассматривай. В любом случае решение надо искать для всей задачи, а не для одного её этапа (может, в решении этого этапа вообще не будет) - но для SO это неформат, это надо на соотв. форуме в теме делать.

Comment: @Akina чем же это она так плоха? В пхп у меня есть возможность сформировать нужный запрос без дублирования кода (с кучей union как я объяснял в другой теме) и без sql-процедур. Значит я смогу использовать результат этого запроса в качестве источника данных другого запроса... Все будет норм.

Comment: Дело твоё... но это вынос серверной логики на клиента. Устраивает? ну делай так, какие проблемы.